# Make a word insensitive case with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I've this .htaccess rule.

```
# Shop-homepage
RewriteRule ABCDEF/fr-CA/$ shop-homepage.php?lang=fr&country=ca&shop=ABCDEF [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ABCDEF/en-CA/$ shop-homepage.php?lang=en&country=ca&shop=ABCDEF [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ABCDEF/en-US/$ shop-homepage.php?lang=en&country=us&shop=ABCDEF [L,QSA]
```

How can I make `ABCDEF` insensitive case ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NC` flag . NC is use to match both uppercase and lowercase characters in URI :

```
RewriteRule ABCDEF/fr-CA/$ shop-homepage.php?lang=fr&country=ca&shop=ABCDEF [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ABCDEF/en-CA/$ shop-homepage.php?lang=en&country=ca&shop=ABCDEF [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ABCDEF/en-US/$ shop-homepage.php?lang=en&country=us&shop=ABCDEF [L,QSA,NC]
```